# MultiValueDictKeyError at /new_search/realme-xt-pearl-blue-64-gb/p/i/realme-xt

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I want to capture the url parameters to views.How can I do it?

views.py

```
def new_search(request,linkadd,text):

    serch = request.GET['linkadd']
    link = request.GET['text']
```

html

```
{% for post in product_names %}

    <a id="link" href="{% url 'new_search' linkadd=post.1  text=post.0  %}" value="{{ post.0 }}">{{ post.0 }}</p>


{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^new_search(?P<linkadd>)/(?P<text>)',views.new_search,name='new_search'),
]
```

I want to get link and text from the url "120.0.0.0:8000/1232-23232-32-2323sdsjdhjas/redmi"
assume :1232-23232-32-2323sdsjdhjas as link and redmi as text

but I get the error like this please suggest me how to do it
MultiValueDictKeyError at /new_search/realme-xt-pearl-blue-64-gb/p/itm731360fdbd273?pid=MOBFJYBE9FHXFEFJ&lid=LSTMOBFJYBE9FHXFEFJNVQVIV&marketplace=FLIPKART&srno=s_1_1&otracker=search&fm=organic&iid=a64429b9-99a5-405b-8edb-9d94934fb991.MOBFJYBE9FHXFEFJ.SEARCH&ssid=iprr3ut7io0000001598430215812&qH=23f6a0071022557e/Realme XT (Pearl Blue, 64 GB)
Please help me..Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing something like this:

**views.py**

```
def new_search(request,linkadd,text):
    linkadd = request.GET['linkadd'] # another choice is linkadd = request.GET.getlist('linkadd')
    text = request.GET['text'] # another choice is text = request.GET.getlist('text')
    context ={
       'linkadd':linkadd,
       'text':text
    }
    return render(request,"my_template.html", context)
```

**my_template.html**

```
<a id="link" href="{% url 'my_app:new_search' linkadd=linkadd  text=text %}" value="{{linkadd}}">{{text}}</a>
```

Here we consider app_name is `my_app`. Please try this.